# Unreachable balcony/items?

Tags: pc, tomb-raider-anniversary

In *Tomb Raider: Anniversary*, just outside the Croft Manor gym there are strange "glows" visible on the upper balcony across the courtyard. They look like halos for Artifacts, but according to the Level Statistics, I've already located all 8 Artifacts in the Manor.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hmm.  I don't recall seeing these in my recent playthrough on Tomb Raider Collection on PS3.  I'll go back and look.

Comment: Do the level statistics show that you're missing anything else? As far as I remember there are more types of collectibles in the game other than just Artifacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I answered my own question. Using the ledge glitch I was able to get a closer look at it. Turns out it's a modeling glitch. The floor of the balcony above is placed too high, so the glow of the lights in the passageway below are visible. The floor itself is invisible when viewed from the courtyard at ground level.

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]